# Is it safer to have an encrypted disk image, inside an encrypted hard drive?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, filesystem

I'm trying to copy 4TB of my data from one hard drive to another.

Both of them have full-disk encryption.

Within my first HD, I store all my files on an encrypted disk image (with the same password as the disk itself).

Also, it's extremely slow: just copying from one HD to the other is going to take me 5-7 days.

- Is there any added security benefit to do that?
- Is this why the copying is incredibly slow?

-Is there a security risk if I create several partition (all encrypted) instead of a full disk encryption?

Comment: What format disks? For Mac APFS format, there is no "full disk" encryption - each APFS volume is encrypted.  You need to explain your risk assessment (what threats are you mitigating) which led you to double encryption. The simple answer to your question is "no", but there could be reasons.

Comment: Safe in what respect? Any time you encrypt a drive you increase your chances of losing *all* the data in one single accident. Wrapping one encrypted structure inside another increases that exponentially.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. When I mean safe I mean preventing unauthorised access.

What are you refering to by "accident"? You mean a file corruption which would ruin the whole disk that is encrypted?

Comment: Drives fail physically, or have their data corrupted, possibly by a sudden disconnect. If that happens to an encrypted rive, it becomes factors harder to recover, because you can't even pick out the surviving bits by hand. Personally, I never use encrypted backups. It's not worth the risk.